# VBA: How to populate one column with IF condition

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, populate

So here's my problem. I've 3 columns with headers. And for this example let's say the first column is a normal text string. The second one is an optional field, which is either empty or filled. The third column is the one to be populated with the following rule: If the 2nd column is not empty, then the first 2 letters of the 1st column should be auto populated to 3rd column. See the picture below.

[Example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhCTh.jpg)

With functions all I'd have to do is to put =IF(B2 <> ""; LEFT(A2;2); "") -formula to all cells in 3rd column. But could someone tell me how would I do the same in VBA? (I have no choice to use the function in this case).

Edit: Thank you for all the answers :)

Comment: Did one of the suggested solutions work for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[5]C[11]<>"""",LEFT(R[5]C,2),"""")"

    'CHANGE C1:C38 TO THE RANGE OF YOUR THIRD COLUMN
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C1:C38"), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

Just adjust `C1:C38` to suit your third column range

Answer (score 1):

This should do it,

```
Sub test()
  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C10").Formula = "=IF(C1 <> """", LEFT(C1,2), """")"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering the data you showed, give this a try...

```
Sub InsertFormula()
Dim lr As Long
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("C2:C" & lr).Formula = "=IF(N2 <> """", LEFT(A2,2), """")"
End Sub
```

The above code assumes that the data lies in column A and B and you need to place the formula in column C starting from Row2 based on the column N.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function myThirdColumn(myFirstColumn, mySecondColumn)
    If mySecondColumn <> "" Then
        myThirdColumn = Left(myFirstColumn, 2)
    Else
        myThirdColumn = ""
    End If
End Function
```